# how to make pagination using xamarin forms with listview with multi columns

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms, grid

I am using [FlowListView](https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/FlowListView) to preview multi-column listview in xamarin forms . 
my question is :
How I could make Pagination with this plugin I used to do it with listview with ItemAppearing Action in normal listview.
if not available to do it with flowListView what is the solution for this ?

Comment: Showing an image which want to archieve, and how about using `CollectionView` to do ? https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/FlowListView

Comment: it's just card in 2 columns with an unknown count of items so I need the pagination to download 10 by 10 items from APi

Comment: Okey, sorry for the wrong link about `CollectionView` .Here is the right link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#horizontal-list .If want to make Pagination , which orientations is need , vertical or horizonal.

Comment: is pagination available to be done with collection view, I need it vertical Pagination

Comment: Unfortunately, after testing in `CollectionView` , can not achieve the pagination function.Then this may need other ways to do.